# How to implement HTTPS access using MyEclipse Tomcat?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, https

I am developing a website using MyEclipse, and the running server is MyEclipse Tomcat. I want to add https access to my website. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In your Tomcat directory you will find a conf directory, and inside that conf directory is a file called server.xml.  Locate the following block of XML:

```
<Connector port=”8443″
    maxThreads=”150″ minSpareThreads=”25″ maxSpareThreads=”75″
    enableLookups=”true” disableUploadTimeout=”true”
    acceptCount=”100″ debug=”0″ scheme=”https” secure=”true”
    clientAuth=”false” sslProtocol=”TLS”
    keystoreFile=”../webapps/techtracer.bin”
    keystorePass=”ttadmin” />
```

If it's commented out, just uncomment it. Your block may look slightly different, but the important thing is that it should have the port="8443" attribute, secure="true", and some other attributes related to SSL.

If you don't see this in your server.xml, simply look for a "Connector" XML element for port 8080 and add this one in below it.

For more reading, check out [Setting Up SSL on Tomcat in 3 Easy Steps](http://techtracer.com/2007/09/12/setting-up-ssl-on-tomcat-in-3-easy-steps/). There is more information in there than you probably need since you're just running this on localhost.

Finally, when you access your project, you'll use the following URLs:

```
http://localhost:8080   # Unsecure, plain HTTP

https://localhost:8443   # Secure HTTPS/SSL version
```

Note the differences in both the protocols (http/https) and the ports (8080/8443).